# active admin saving selection from collection_select and passing to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

hi i am using active admin for my app i have a partial with a drop down list where the menu and recipe are populated this page is to group the recipe in a menu
_menu_recipe.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @menu_recipe] do |f| %>

<p>
 <%= f.collection_select :recipe_id,
  Recipe.all,:id,:name,:prompt => true%>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.collection_select :menu_id,
  Menu.all,:id,:name,:prompt => true%>
</p>   
<%= f.buttons :commit %>
<%end%>
```

when ever i try to catch the and create or group it, it comes with a 
`Couldn't find Recipe without an ID` error

my active admin controller which i override is

```
ActiveAdmin.register MenuRecipe do
    menu :parent => "Manage Package"

   form :partial => "menu_recipe"

    controller do
      def new
        new! do |format|
          @menu_recipe = MenuRecipe.new  
        end
      end

      def create
        create! do |format|
          recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
          menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
          @menu_recipe = @menu.add_recipe(menu.id)

          if @menu_recipe.save
            redirect_to {admin_menu_recipe_url}
          end
        end  
      end
    end

end
```

i cant seems to get the current menu and recipe that i group

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 'inspecting' the params hash? This parts seems to be wrong:

```
recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
```

I would have expected something like:

```
recipe = Recipe.find(params[:menu_recipe][:recipe_id])
menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_recipe][:menu_id])
```